# Routes: resources, use member or collection for a custom action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi everyone I am doing a application with rails 3.2. I am trying to use `form_tag` but I have problem with the route.

I try this in my form:

```
= form_tag('/companies/save_category', method: "post") do
```

and this:

```
= form_tag({:controller => "companies", :action=>"save_category"}, method: "post") do
```

In my `config/routes.rb`:

I am a little confused to put route like this

```
resources :companies do
  post 'save_category'
end
```

or route like this:

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    post 'save_category'
  end
end
```

But either way does not work. And when I execute `rake routes`, I obtain the same result

```
company_save_category POST   /companies/:company_id/save_category(.:format)          companies#save_category
```

The error was this

```
No route matches [POST] "/companies/save_category"
```

any idea?

Comment: you need to add the company_id to the path: `{:controller => "companies", :action=>"save_category", :company_id => @company.id}` -- Or better, use the path helper: `form_tag(save_category_company_path(@company), method: :post)`

Comment: thanks @MrYoshiji works perfect, but is the same to put in the route like a member or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these routes:

```
resources :companies do
  member do
    post 'save_category'
  end
end
```

This member block means that the route `save_category` in the `/compagnies/` namespace will need a Company id to work:

```
/compagnies/12/save_category # where 12 is params[:company_id]
```

Now, with collection:

```
resources :companies do
  collection do
    post 'save_category'
  end
end
```

This means that to get to the save_category route, you don't need the company id:

```
/compagnies/save_category # will work, is not needing a params[:company_id]
```

---

**In your case**, you should first use the url helpers (generated following the routes.rb). You need here:

```
if save_category is a *member route*
  save_category_company_path(@company)

elsif save_category is a *collection route*
  save_category_companies_path
```

I guess the category you want to save is related to a specific company, right? If yes, you need a member route:

```
form_tag(save_category_company_path(@company), method: "post") do
```

Hope this helps!